# How to use Framing to separate on several delimiters?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Very simple use case:

I am streaming a text file. According to the encoding of the system, newline characters can be `\r`, `\n` or `\n\r`. How do I use `Framing.delimiter` to be able to match on any one of those 3?

Right now I have:

```
Framing
  .delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 100000, allowTruncation = true)
  .map(_.utf8String)
```

But that only matches on `\n` and `\n\r` and leaves out a potential `\r` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just filter `\r` out before sending stream of chars to framing.

```
.filterNot(_ == `\r`)
```